# Prove that any $n+1$ integers has a pair of integers differ by a multiple of $n$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

My attempt : 
Take any $n+1$ integers $1,2,.....,n+1$ , 
Then there is a pair of integers $1, n+1$ such that :

$$(n+1)-1 = n$$, which is a multiple of n.

Comment: $1,\ldots,n+1$ isn't **any** set of $n+1$ integers.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Divide each of the $n+1$ numbers by $n$. Since there divisor is $n$ you will get $n$ distinct remainders. But there are $n+1$ numbers hence two numbers will leave the same remainder when divided by $n$. The difference of these two numbers will be divisible by $n$ since their remainders will cancel out.

Comment: Why down vote? Happy to know if there is anything wrong.

Comment: I didn't down vote, so I don't know why the person did it.  However, since you ask for any improvements, there's nothing specifically wrong, but the end of your second sentence is somewhat misleading where you wrote "you will get $n$ remainders". Actually, you get $n + 1$ remainders as there are $n + 1$ numbers. What you mean is something like that the set of possible remainders has $n$ values. You may wish to reword it appropriately.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I mean $n$ distinct remainders. Thanks

Comment: +1 - You're welcome. Just adding the word "distinct", as you stated in your comment & then changed your answer accordingly, is a better idea than my suggestion.